Как обойти ошибку 403 через Scrapy?
Решил попробовать со скрапить карточки циан, но при запуске scrapy shell и потом fetch('https://kazan.cian.ru/cat.php?deal_type=sale&engine_version=2&offer_type=flat&p=1&region=4777&room1=1') , то вылетает ошибка 403, что делать?

В дополнение к ошибке, сервер не возвращает никакой поясняющей информации?

403 ошибка сообщает что запрос отклонён сервером, попробуйте добавить заголовки к запросу, скорее всего это поможет

Возможный дубликат вопроса: 403 Forbidden почему?

Ошибка 403 (Forbidden) — это стандартный код ответа HTTP, означающий, что доступ к запрошенному ресурсу запрещён. Сервер блокирует Ваш запрос, в 99% случаев это связанно с отсутствием заголовков в запросе.
Попробуйте добавить заголовок User-Agent - чтобы Ваш запрос был похож на запрос от браузера.
headers = { 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.3'}
fetch('https://kazan.cian.ru/cat.php?deal_type=sale&engine_version=2&offer_type=flat&p=1&region=4777&room1=1', headers=headers)


